# Loop keys in dictionary to send an email (Python)

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, email, key

I am trying to loop over a key in a dictionary that has 4 items in total.
However, it doesn't go through all of them and only shows the key of the last item.

```
Prueba = {"A":"###@gmail.com",
"B":"###@gmail.com",
"C":"###@gmail.com"}
with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587) as zero:
   zero.ehlo()
   zero.starttls()
   zero.ehlo()
   zero.login(Emaill, Passs)
   for keyyy in Prueba.keys():
      subject = 'Subject {0}'.format(keyyy)
   for keyyy in Prueba.keys():
      body = 'Body {0}. Body2 {1}.'.format(keyyy,keyyy)
   msg = f'subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'
   for keyy in pp.Prueba:
      zero.sendmail(Emaill,Prueba[keyy],msg)
```

When the email is sent. All the emails only show the key of the last item ("C"). I want to show each email with its respective key.

Comment: When you do this `for keyyy in Prueba.keys(): subject = 'Subject {0}'.format(keyyy)` you are updating the value of `subject` three times before you try to use it for anything.  I think you want a single `for key, value in Preuba.items()` loop that has the subject, body, msg and zero.sendmail code in the body of that one loop

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is use one loop for every action you wanna do, instead do one loop for all the actions:

```
Prueba = {"A":"###@gmail.com",
"B":"###@gmail.com",
"C":"###@gmail.com"}
with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587) as zero:
   zero.ehlo()
   zero.starttls()
   zero.ehlo()
   zero.login(Emaill, Passs)
   for keyyy in Prueba.keys():
      subject = 'Subject {0}'.format(keyyy)
      body = 'Body {0}. Body2 {1}.'.format(keyyy,keyyy)
      msg = f'subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'
      zero.sendmail(Emaill,Prueba[keyy],msg)
```

This should have the right subject and body in the right mail. Haven't actually tested the code yet, but that's the way it should work.